# Can I start a new SSH terminal without re-authenticating?

Tags: ssh, terminal

Is there a relatively simple way to start a new terminal (ideally within a new window) within a pre-existing SSH terminal?

As in:

```
chuck@mycomputer:~$ ssh myserver
Enter passphrase for key '/home/chuck/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Linux 2.6 SMP Tue Jul 17 11:13:12 EDT 2007 i686
chuck@myserver:~$

[insert magic here]

[ ...a new gnome-terminal (or the like) appears with chuck@myserver:~$ ]
```

I'm not interested in using X11 forwarding.  I feel like putty supports this... but haven't a windows machine around to check with.

Comment: As an alternative to a new window, I would recommend the excellent GNU `screen` -- it has the massive advantage that it survives a severed connection and can be resumed from anywhere at any time.

Comment: awesome. I think `screen` has one of the largest need-vs-known ration :-) Once you get hooked, it's hard to imagine a life before `screen`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Add this to your ~/.ssh/config:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sock_%r@%h:%p
```

I believe this will do what you want... if not, please clarify your question. :)

Comment: I guess the duplication of connections is really part of what I'm trying to avoid here.  I was looking for multiple terminals over one connection.  (GNU Screen did it)

Comment: That's exactly what my suggestion does--multiple terminals over a single connection.  Although screen is also a good answer.  My solution has the advantage of letting other non-terminal connections go over the same connection as well--such as rsync, scp, etc.  I use both ssh's control master feature and screen all day long, every day of the year.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Screen gives me pretty much exactly what I wanted: [Screen User's Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

Comment: you sidestepped the question :)